# Mapping function to manipulate URLs, groovyscript

Tags: groovy

I am trying to manipulate a number of URLs using groovyscript.

The URLs have been output in the form:

```
http://wiki.somecompany.com/FOLDER/file/attach/FOLDER/test/random.txt
```

where `FOLDER` is one of a list of different folder names.

These URLs actually need to be transformed to the following:

```
http://wiki.somecompany.com/pub/FOLDER/test/random.txt
```

I can change one folder at a time with this code:

```
def longFOLDERName = "FOLDER/file/attach/FOLDER";
def FOLDERName = "pub/FOLDER";

displayURL = url.replaceAll(longFOLDERName,FOLDERName);
```

Repeating it for each different folder name, but obviously this is time consuming and inefficient.

How do I select the text between `.com/` and `/file`, compare it with the folder name after attach/, and then turn the whole thing into a function?

The string value of the URL is stored as displayURL.

Comment: Why do you want to compare the strings? after that you will go with replacing string right? What I want to say is the ```replaceAll``` function is wont be less better than your own implementation

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can go with regular expressions.

```
def url = 'http://wiki.somecompany.com/MY_FOLDER/file/attach/MY_FOLDER/test/random.txt'
def regex = /^http:\/\/wiki\.somecompany\.com\/(.+)\/file\/attach\/(.+)\/test\/random\.txt$/

def matcher = (url =~ regex)
def folder = matcher[0][1] // here you get your "MY_FOLDER"

def resultUrl = "http://wiki.somecompany.com/pub/$folder/test/random.txt" // here you make string interpolation
```

As you may notice, the `(.+)` matches any string. The `[0]` gets you the list of matches (`[http://wiki.somecompany.com/MY_FOLDER/file/attach/MY_FOLDER/test/random.txt, MY_FOLDER, MY_FOLDER]`) and the `[1]` is the folder name you care about.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
def stringInput = "http://wiki.somecompany.com/FOLDER/file/attach/FOLDER/test/random.txt";
def stringSplit = stringInput.split("/");

i=0;
while (stringSplit[i] != "attach"){
i++;
}


if ( i+1 != stringSplit.length && stringSplit[i-2] ==stringSplit[i+1] && stringSplit[i-1]=="file"){
def stringOutput = stringInput.replaceAll(stringSplit[i+1]+"/file/attach","pub");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regexp to capture more than just `FOLDER`.

```
def urls = [
"http://wiki.somecompany.com/FOLDER/file/attach/FOLDER/test/random.txt",
"http://wiki.somecompany.com/OTHER/file/attach/OTHER/something/random.html",
]

def r = /(FOLDER|OTHER)\/file\/attach\/\1/
//       ^             ^               ^
//       |             |               +-- backref first group
//       |             +-- Stuff in between you want get rid off
//       +-- All folder names, you want to change

assert [
"http://wiki.somecompany.com/pub/FOLDER/test/random.txt",
"http://wiki.somecompany.com/pub/OTHER/something/random.html",
] == urls.collect{
    it.replaceAll(r, 'pub/$1') // replace the whole match with `/pub/` 
                               // and the value of the first group
}
```